# Can Villager Bed Assignments be Forced?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm building my own village, using an existing village as a starting point. I've retained four of the original structures, built a few of my own including a barracks (currently 3-beds) near my farming fields. The intention was that my farmers could live communally.

Instead the barracks is inhabited by a weaponsmith, toolsmith, and fisherman - all of whose job blocks are at the smithy which is on the diagonal opposite end of town from those beds.  The bed in the smithy is slept in by the librarian whose work station is next to the farm....

While this makes for interesting commuting patterns in the morning, it's really not on theme. So obviously villagers don't select a bed based on its proximity to their job. Can I force this in some way to assign housing to specific villagers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always break all the other job blocks available besides the one you want them to use, forcing them to use it, then trade with them to lock in their job (if you didn't know trading with a villager makes it keep its job). Then just replace the next blocks you want your villagers to use, and just work your way through.

Comment: Seems this is, indeed, the only realistic option for now. Thanks!